# How to bind multiple snippets to one input field in a form

Tags: scala, lift

I'am trying to have auto complete and onBlur functionality attached to the same input field using Liftweb framework.

I have them working independently.

What I'am trying to do is have an auto complete input field and on selecting the value from the suggestion, some business logic is to be performed and another input field needs to be updated.

But only the auto complete feature is working.

This is the form

```
<form class="lift:CapitalOnBlur">
  Country : <input id="countryNameOnBlur" type="text" name="countryNameOnBlur"/><br />
  Capital: <input id="capitalNameOnBlur" type="text" name="capital"/>
</form>
```

This is the snippet

```
object CapitalOnBlur {

  val capitals: Map[String, String] = Map(
    "india" -> "New Delhi",
    "uganda" -> "Kampala",
    "japan" -> "Tokyo")

  def render = {

    def callback(countryName: String): JsCmd = {
      val capital = capitals.getOrElse(countryName.toLowerCase, "Not Found")
      SetValById("capitalNameOnBlur", capital)
    }

    val default = ""

    def suggest(value: String, limit: Int) = capitals.filter(_._1.startsWith(value.toLowerCase)).keys.toSeq

    def submit(value: String) = Unit

    "#countryNameOnBlur" #> AutoComplete(default, suggest, submit) &
    "#countryNameOnBlur [onBlur]" #> SHtml.onEvent(callback)
  }
}
```

This is what I actually want to do. I tried this and only onBlur event is triggered.

According to my needs, When I start typing the country name in the first input field, it should show me the suggestions and on selecting the suggestion i.e.; onBlur from that input field, the corresponding capital should be rendered in the next input field.

And also is there a way to trigger an action on selecting a suggestion using the inbuilt Auto complete feature of lift.

Comment: can you post any relevant code? How are you binding to the events to your form? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @jcern I've made edit's to the question.

Comment: I still don't entirely understand what you are trying to do. What events are you trying to bind to - `OnChange`, `OnClick`, `OnBlur`, etc...? I assume both methods return a `JsCmd`? You say autocomplete is working, but it is not referred to at all in the example. What is your desired result?

Comment: @jcern: I want to bind OnBlur and autocomplete events to one input filed. And that is what I'am not understanding. How do I do the same. Do you want me to post the code of both the methods?

Comment: Posting the code might be helpful. Autocomplete is not an event, but a typical implementation might utilize an `onchange` handler. Also, what would be helpful would be what you want the output to be - like: `<input onblur="getCapitalName" onchange="autoComplete">` or something.

Comment: That is what i exactly want to accomplish. Could you guide me on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding this as a separate answer since the edit is essentially a separate question. The AutoComplete widget from Lift does not modify an existing element on the page, but rather replaces it with the following `NodeSeq`, as [per the source](https://github.com/liftmodules/widgets/blob/master/src/main/scala/net/liftmodules/widgets/autocomplete/AutoComplete.scala#L120).

```
  <span>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href={"/" + LiftRules.resourceServerPath +"/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css"} type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src={"/" + LiftRules.resourceServerPath +"/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"} />
      {Script(onLoad)}
    </head>
    <input type="text" id={id} value={default.openOr("")} />
    <input type="hidden" name={hidden} id={hidden} value={defaultNonce.openOr("")} />
  </span>
```

Since that has now replaced the original HTML, the second line where you add an `onBlur` handler is not applied to anything useful. However, the `AutoComplete` constructor does take an optional parameter for attributes and you can probably use that to add an `onBlur` attribute to the input tag.

You can try something like this:

```
"#countryNameOnBlur" #> AutoComplete(default, suggest, submit, 
  ("onBlur", SHtml.onEvent(callback).cmd.toJsCmd))
```

The above should pass in a tuple which specifies the attribute name, and the string representation of the Javascript you want executed. This should accomplish what you are looking for as long as the AutoComplete library doesn't also rely on the `onBlur` event. That case is doable too, but a bit more work.

One other thing to note is that `onBlur` is fired when the input loses focus, ie: the user moves the cursor to another field. If you want it to fire any time the text changes, regardless of cursor position, you may prefer the `onChange` event.

Comment: I tried doing that but get an error, not so familiar with the framework and facing issues. 
The following code
`"onBlur" -> SHtml.onEvent(callback).cmd.toJsCmd`
returns : `net.liftweb.util.Helpers.TheStrBindParam`
where as it requires `(String, String)` 
 
Not understanding what to do.

Comment: After finding out what the problem was finally figured out how to get it done. This is what actually worked for me. `"#countryNameOnBlur" #> AutoComplete(default, suggest _, submit _, ("onBlur", SHtml.onEvent(callback).cmd.toJsCmd))`. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You are right, that argument looks for a tuple of `String,String`. There is an implicit conversion that gets imported when you issue `import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._` which converts `_ -> _` to `(_, _)`, but for clarity it would have been better to use the Scala default syntax. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to bind to different events on the same element, so that you end up with something like: `<input onblur="getCapitalName" onchange="autoComplete">`, you can try using `SHtml.onEvent`. Something like this in your snippet should do the trick:

```
object CapitalOnBlur {
  def render = 
    "* [onblur]" #> SHtml.onEvent(e => CapitalOnBlur.getCapitalName(e)) &
    "* [onchange]" #> SHtml.onEvent(e => CapitalOnBlur.autoComplete(e)) &

  ...
}
```

And then call the snippet from your input, like this:

```
<form>
  Country : <input id="countryNameOnBlur" data-lift="CapitalOnBlur" type="text" name="countryNameOnBlur"/><br />
</form>
```

I am not sure what any of the arguments your code takes, so the above is mostly illustrative - but will hopefully get you on your way.

Comment: thank you. I will try this out and let you know if i face any difficulty. And is there any suggestion on learning Liftweb or any pointers which will help me speed up the learning curve. I just started with it 2 weeks back.

Comment: With Lift, I think the best way to learn is to dive in, and just ask for help if you need it. The Lift [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb) is an extremely friendly community that loves to help people get the most out of Lift - and reading through the list, you'll see a bunch of solutions to problems people encounter. If you want a good starting reference, [Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/) will give you a good overview. Finally, the [Lift Cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/) has some great examples of things people often try to accomplish.

Comment: I am going through both the resources you mentioned along with an additional Exploring Lift resource. As I am new to Lift as well as Web development it's taking quite a while to digest the high level concepts. But glad to see People like you around, ready to help people like me when they are stuck. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. One thing to point out with Exploring Lift - the concepts are all very relevant, however most of their examples use an old syntax `bind` which are the predecessor to the newer `CSS Selector` binding (which is used in the answer). For now, they are both valid in the production version of Lift, but I would highly recommend you use the CSS Selector.

Comment: I've edited the code, could you help me with the same.